# Multi caret android studio shortcut

Tags: android, android-studio

For some reason i have lost the default `(Shift + Alt + click)` shortcut for `multi caret` selection in `Android Studio`. Does anybody know how can i reset it or find the current or at last put my own shortcut..?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Settings... and type "add or remove caret" in the search at the top right to see what the shortcut is currently set to. You can also change it.

Answer (score 0):

Multicaret can be acheived using:

- **Mouse** or mouse with keyboard

  - Hold `middle click`
  - Using the specified shortcut
    [image: settings1]
- **Keyboard**

  - Using `Double ctrl`
    [image: settings]